# what is LLVM ExtractValueInst?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I was studying one llvm code, where i have found a line,

```
const ExtractValueInst *EI = cast<ExtractValueInst>(I);
st.setValue(I, st.getValue(EI->getAggregateOperand()));
```

Now, I understand why cast<...> is being used, but I can't relate with the ExtarctValueInst, Can you give me one example what is this instruction in IR and what is the equivalence C code? and also I want to know about getAggregateOperand() function also. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a function that returns a 32-bit integer that isn't really one integer, but rather a set of smaller bitfields and/or bools. Perhaps the bottom six bits are an integer in the range 0-63, the seventh bit is a boolean, etc.

Somewhere you have a call to that function, and a little below the call, you have code that uses the i6 that's a part of the return value. So you create an extractvalue to extract a value from the composite return value. (If the composite were in main memory you'd probably create a getelementptr/load pair, but since it's most likely in a CPU register you create an extractvalue.)

This is quite often used e.g. in exception handling; a catch clause has a single parameter which is a composite of two things, and the catch clause tests one of the two components to determine whether to catch the exception or pass it on.

Comment: One additional note, ExtractValue requires an aggregate type, like `{ i32, i32 }`. You can't just use it to grab an i32 out of an i64.

Comment: Right. I tried to talk my way past that point by the "returns a 32-bit integer that isn't" verbiage, but perhaps I shouldn't have. The function's declared return type in IR has to be a struct whose total size is the same as the size of `i32`.